# d3.csv.parse only parses first line of csv string

Tags: javascript, parsing, csv, d3.js

I'd like to allow a user to populate a textbox with a csv string (sample shown below) and then parse with d3.csv.parse.

```
x,y,series,size
2,-0.083014839,Group 0,0.883928284
-9,0.355697349,Group 0,0.149154477
5,-0.256459661,Group 0,0.066308001
3,-0.243723214,Group 0,0.388138931
-7,0.776456119,Group 4,0.481110901
```

When I grab the val() within the textbox it's only able to save the first row of the csv string to a variable in javascript and then errors out. How do I save the whole csv string to a variable so I can send to d3.csv.parse?

Comment: Why did you post a separate question for this? Isn't this what you're asking in the other one?

Comment: Trying to get answer for a more specific problem now!

Answer (score 0):

This was happening with me. The problem was using the **d3.csv.parse()** in the same way I was using **d3.csv()**. For example:

```js
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  //Do something with the data
}
```

So, I tried to use **d3.csv.parse** like this:

```js
d3.csv.parse(variable_with_csv, function(data) {
  //Do something with the data
}
```

But this is **WRONG**. The second parameter is an accessor not the call back with the data. The correct way to do what you want is simply get the data directly:

```js
data = d3.csv.parse(variable_with_csv)
```